# Freeing dynamic 2D array not working as expected in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, free, dynamic-arrays

When I run code like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    int i, count = 0x09;
    int sizei = 5, sizej = 2;

    int **ary = malloc (sizei * sizeof **ary);
    for (i = 0; i < sizei; i++) {
        *(ary + i) = malloc (sizej * sizeof *(ary + i));
        **(ary + i) = ++count;
        printf (" %2d |%p| +%x+ \n", i, (ary + i), *(*(ary + i)));
    }

    puts("----");
    for (i = sizei - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf (" %2d |%p| +%x+ \n", i, (ary + i), *(*(ary + i)));
        free (*(ary + i));   
    }
    puts("----");

    free (ary);
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect that the first half would create a 2d dynamic array of ints called `ary` (i.e a pointer to a dynamically allocated array of pointers, each pointing to a dynamically allocated array of ints). The 0th element of each array `**(ary + i)` would then be recursively assigned the current value of `count`.

The second half would iterate in reverse, freeing each element of `ary` in the reverse it was malloc'd, followed by freeing `ary` itself.

This appears to work fine until I try to free `*(ary + 0)`, at which point I get a double free / corruption error. I've included the output.

```
  0 |0x1d6f010| +a+ 
  1 |0x1d6f018| +b+ 
  2 |0x1d6f020| +c+ 
  3 |0x1d6f028| +d+ 
  4 |0x1d6f030| +e+ 
----
  4 |0x1d6f030| +e+ 
  3 |0x1d6f028| +d+ 
  2 |0x1d6f020| +c+ 
  1 |0x1d6f018| +b+ 
  0 |0x1d6f010| +1d6f0b0+ 
*** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000001d6f030 ***
```

I'm curious why the 0th element of the 0th element of `ary` (i.e `*(*(ary + 0) + 0))` or just `**ary`) became what looks like some memory address (only slighly) out of bounds from what's taken up by this 2d array once it got out of the first loop.

And if I get rid of the second loop and just try to free `ary` directly without first freeing any of its elements I get something like:

```
  0 |0x1d6f010| +a+ 
  1 |0x1d6f018| +b+ 
  2 |0x1d6f020| +c+ 
  3 |0x1d6f028| +d+ 
  4 |0x1d6f030| +e+ 
----
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000001d6f010 ***
```

I don't understand what I've done wrong here. Would using array notation make a difference? I need any solutions to allow me to have a dynamic length of each array independant of the length of the rest of the elements of `ary` if at all possible. The number elements of `ary` wouldn't necesarily be known at compile time either. I'm using gcc 4.9 if that's relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem 1**

```
int **ary = malloc (sizei * sizeof **ary);
```

is equivalent to

```
int **ary = malloc (sizei * sizeof int);
```

If `sizeof` a pointer is less than `sizeof(int)` in your system, you end up accessing memory out of bounds.

You need to use:

```
int **ary = malloc (sizei * sizeof *ary);
```

or

```
int **ary = malloc (sizei * sizeof(int*));
```

**Problem 2**

```
*(ary + i) = malloc (sizej * sizeof *(ary + i));
```

needs to be

```
*(ary + i) = malloc (sizej * sizeof **(ary + i));
```

or

```
*(ary + i) = malloc (sizej * sizeof int);
```

or

```
ary[i] = malloc (sizej * sizeof *ary[i]);
```

or

```
ary[i] = malloc (sizej * sizeof int);
```

Answer (score 0):

`ari` is pointer a to array of pointer, so size of elements are pointers. In your code, you use `sizeof **ary` which is an `int`

```
    int **ary = malloc (sizei * sizeof **ary);
```

For each of the pointer to array of `int` elements. In your malloc for those pointers, you use `sizeof *(ary+i)` which is a pointer to `int`

```
        *(ary + i) = malloc (sizej * sizeof *(ary + i));
```

sizeof(int) is not always the same as sizeof(int*). In fact, on most 64 bits systems, which I suspect is what you use, sizeof(int)==4 and sizeof(int*)==8.

My guess is that you are using such a system, and because of that, you do not allocate enough memory for the main `ari` pointer and you are overflowing it with values, thrashing the content of critical memory management data so future malloc() and free() call have a big chance of failing completely.